# Windows 10 BLE low performance

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am running the BLE sample application of Windows 10, connecting to a peripheral and sending data.
This peripheral can get a few KB/sec from Android application. The rate from the Windows application is about 130 B/sec. Is there a way to increase the rate? I don't see any configuration file or any other way to affect the rate of sending data over BLE by using Windows.Devices.Bluetooth library.

I tried sending bulks of 70 bytes in high rate and expected the data to arrive at the target in at least 10KB/sec (BLE 4.2 performance is 1Mbps)

```
    public async void BLE_ConnectionAsync(string ble_name)
    {
        bool bleCharacteristicsConnect = false;
        try
        {
            if(!bleCharacteristicsConnect)
            {
                if (ble_name != null)
                {
                    nameBle = ble_name;
                    string[] requestedProperties = { "System.Devices.Aep.DeviceAddress", "System.Devices.Aep.IsConnected" };
                    deviceWatcher = DeviceInformation.CreateWatcher(
                        BluetoothLEDevice.GetDeviceSelectorFromPairingState(false),
                    requestedProperties,
                        DeviceInformationKind.AssociationEndpoint);
                    deviceWatcher.Added += DevicedWatcher_Added;
                    deviceWatcher.Updated += DevicedWatcher_Updated;
                    deviceWatcher.Removed += DevicedWatcher_Removed;
                    deviceWatcher.EnumerationCompleted += DevicedWatcher_EnumerationCompleted;
                    deviceWatcher.Stopped += DevicedWatcher_Stopped;
                    deviceWatcher.Start();

                    while (true)
                    {
                        if (device == null)
                        {
                            Thread.Sleep(200);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            bluetoothLEDevice = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromIdAsync(device.Id);

                            result = await bluetoothLEDevice.GetGattServicesAsync();

                            if (result.Status == GattCommunicationStatus.Success)
                            {
                                var services = result.Services;

                                bool shouldExit = false;
                                foreach (var service in services)
                                {
                                    string test = service.Uuid.ToString("N");
                                    
                                    string test2 = service.Uuid.ToString("N").Substring(4, 4);
                                    Console.WriteLine("Service id: " + test2);
                                    if (service.Uuid.ToString("N").Substring(4, 4) == "fe40" || service.Uuid.ToString("N").Substring(4, 4) == HEART_RATE_SERVICE_ID)

                                    {

                                        GattCharacteristicsResult characteristicsResult = await service.GetCharacteristicsAsync();

                                        if (characteristicsResult.Status == GattCommunicationStatus.Success)
                                        {
                                            var characteristics = characteristicsResult.Characteristics;
                                            foreach (var characteristic in characteristics)
                                            {
                                                GattCharacteristicProperties properties = characteristic.CharacteristicProperties;

                                                try
                                                {

                                                    GattCommunicationStatus status = await characteristic.WriteClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorAsync(GattClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorValue.Notify);

                                                    if (status == GattCommunicationStatus.Success)
                                                    {
                                                        characteristic.ValueChanged += Characteristic_ValueChanged;
                                                        selectedCharacteristic = characteristic;
                                                        Console.WriteLine("Read char "+characteristic.Uuid.ToString("N"));
                                                    }
                                                    else
                                                    {

                                                    }
                                                }
                                                catch (Exception ex)
                                                {
                                                    bleCharacteristicsConnect = true;
                                                    writeChar = characteristic;
                                                    Console.WriteLine("Write char " + characteristic.Uuid.ToString("N"));
                                                    OpenComPort(ble_name);
                                                    shouldExit = true;
                                                    break;
                                                }

                                            }

                                            if (shouldExit)
                                            {
                                                break;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                                break;

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
          
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error(ex.Message);

        }
      
    }



    private async void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;

            byte[] data = new byte[sp.BytesToRead];
            if(data.Length> MAX_PAYLOAD_SIZE)
            {
                sp.Read(data, 0, data.Length);

                byte[] _data = new byte[MAX_PAYLOAD_SIZE];
                
                int countPackets = (data.Length) / MAX_PAYLOAD_SIZE;
                int remainder = (data.Length) % MAX_PAYLOAD_SIZE;
                log.Info(" [COM --> BLE] \t Data Length = " + data.Length + " Data = " + ByteArrayToString(data));
                
                int i = 0;
                for (i = 0; i < countPackets; i++)
                {
                    await writeChar.WriteValueAsync(data.AsBuffer(i * MAX_PAYLOAD_SIZE, MAX_PAYLOAD_SIZE));
                }
                if (remainder > 0)
                {
                    await writeChar.WriteValueAsync(data.AsBuffer(i * MAX_PAYLOAD_SIZE, remainder)); 
                }


            }
           else
            {
                sp.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                await writeChar.WriteValueAsync(data.AsBuffer());
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            log.Error(ex.Message);
        }


    }
```

Comment: I do not think there is any easy way to do that except switch from WinRT BLE API to legacy one.

Comment: Any recommended library with a good performance?

Comment: 32feet, Bluetooth Framework

Comment: Could you at least display your code or your high level setup? Like do you use Write Without Response or Write With Response? And what connection parameters do you use?

Comment: Added to the description the connection and the writing to the characteristic